# Debug C++ program in VS2010

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010

I am having two C++ programs let us say "test1" and "test2" binaries build in windows using VS2010. My logic is such that "test1" starts "test2". Now i want to debug through step through "test2" when it is started by test1, so i kept break point in program of test2 and debug binary is build.

Now I started released version of "test1" and as expected test2 is started (note that i don't have released version  of test2 build) so we know that only debug version is started. But when test2 is started i am expecting to stop at break point, but it is not stopping. When i am launching debug version of test2 from VS IDE it is stopping at break point.

How can we debug the test2 when it is started by test1? How can we achieve this in windows.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the "attach to running process" option when starting the debugger.  Run test1 normally, and when it spawns the test2 process you can attach the debugger to it:

[image: From the debug menu]

[image: Process selection dialog]

Comment: May I add that you might need to Sleep() test2 for a few seconds so it gives you time to attach to it

Comment: Instead of a sleep, just display a message box. It should give you as much as time as you need to attach, and you won't be racing against the clock to attach before the Sleep method returns.

Answer (score 1):

You need to start a debug session of the test2 project (not test1) and specify in the project properties of test2 the executable to run. This is under Configuration Properties->Debugging->Command. Set this value to test1.exe.

Comment: Personally I prefer $(TargetPath) as the debugging command. that way if you rename your binary, it still works.

Comment: @C Johnson: but $(TargetPath) will point to the wrong executable, test1.exe needs to be executed when starting the debugger for the test2.exe project - so the test2.exe project is the active project when you press F5.

Answer (score 1):

You have two possible approaches:

**Attach to Process**

1. Make the test2 project active in Visual Studio.
2. Start test1, which in turn starts the test2 process.
3. Use Debug | Attach to Process and select the test2 process.

This is fine if you don't need to debug the startup of the process.

**Project Configuration**

1. Make the test2 project active in Visual Studio.
2. Open Project | Configuration | Configuration Properties | Debugging.
3. Set Command to the full path to test1.exe.

Generally this alternative is much more productive and allows you to debug startup.